# Watir Rspec Table Cell

Tags: rspec, watir, watir-webdriver, tableheader

Now I have the problem that I can identify the text in a table.

For [this Site](http://www.bod.de/hilfe/coverberechnung.html)
I choose from

1. Paperback
2. weiß 90g
3. 12 cm x 19 cm
4. number of pages: 24
5. Click "Cover berechnen"

Test with test::unit okay

```
assert(@browser.th(:text => "Buchrückenbreite").exists?)
assert(@browser.td(:text => "0.13 cm").exists?)
```

Test with rspec incorrect

```
@browser.th(:text => "Buchrückenbreite").should == true
@browser.td(:text => "0.13 cm").should == true
```

Error Message:

```
expected: true
     got: #<Watir::TableHeaderCell:0x..fc61f5c1d071c696a located=false selector={:text=>"Buchrückenbreite", :tag_name=>"th"}> (using ==)
Diff:
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
-true
+#<Watir::TableHeaderCell:0x..fc61f5c1d071c696a located=false selector={:text=>"Buchrückenbreite", :tag_name=>"th"}>
```

Another test:

```
expect(@browser.th(:text => "Buchrückenbreite")).to be_true
```

Error Message:

> `expected #<Watir::TableHeaderCell:0x007fd9452034d0> to respond to`
>   `true?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if an object exists, you can use [RSpec's `exist matcher`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-5/docs/built-in-matchers/exist-matcher).

In the 'should' syntax:

```
@browser.th(:text => "Buchrückenbreite").should exist
@browser.td(:text => "0.13 cm").should exist
```

Or in the 'expect' syntax:

```
expect(@browser.th(:text => "Buchrückenbreite")).to exist
expect(@browser.td(:text => "0.13 cm")).to exist
```